# display empty/blank table if query returns false

Tags: php

what would be the proper implementation of displaying an empty/blank table or just the table header if query result is empty?

**note/conditions
no page redirection
no creation of two tables, one for query with empty result and one for query with results

or is there a much, much  better way to do this?
here is a sample code:

```
<?php if(isset($result)){ ?>  
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>  

<?php foreach($result as $key => $data){?>
<tr>  
    <td><?php echo $data['name'];?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $data['email_add'];?></td>   
</tr>   
<?php }?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

the problem here is that it still throws an error on foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the query result returns false return an empty array instead

I hope this help , and ready for more help if needed

Answer (score 1):

**About the exception:**

You check if `$results` is set, but then you try to loop over `$result` (without a trailing s). I believe you have a typo, which might be a part of the problem. Fixing the typo and making sure that the result is not empty (it might be set, but still empty) will probably fix the exception being thrown.

**About always showing the header:**

To display the header no matter what, move the if-statement to just before the the loop.

**FYI - About well formatted HTML-tables:**

To declare a header on a table, you usually make use of the `<thead>` element - to separate it from the content of the table. An example of a well-formatted HTML-table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>john@email.com</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[**More on formatting tables**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table)

In your case, I would put the loop around the `<tr>` element within the `<tbody>`.

Comment: The variable will be set but its false !!

Comment: @Sedz Added a note about checking for empty as well, thanks for that, that wouldn't be enough though, since the code still contain a typo. Therefor I'm having a hard time justifying the downvote. Non of the information I've given is inaccurate as I see it? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hey man :) , the down vote was for the previous answer , this answer is very informative and clear

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($result) && !empty($result)): ?>  
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Email</td>
    </tr>  

    <?php foreach($result as $data): ?>
    <tr>  
        <td><?php echo $data['name'];?></td>  
        <td><?php echo $data['email_add'];?></td>   
    </tr>   
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
    No results found.
<?php endif ?>
```

Note that I prefer to use the long-form of statements for PHP templates, as it greatly improves readability.